# Pushing a docker image into Artifactory via the publishing mechanism in gradle

Tags: gradle, docker, artifactory

We are using the [Gradle Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) to publish artifacts into our Artifactory server (see also these [instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Gradle)).

Now we have added tasks into our Gradle scripts to build Docker images and we want to push these images into our Artifactory (which we have configured as a Docker repository).

I've managed to do this using custom tasks but I would really like to plug this into our current workflow so that `gradle artifactoryPublish` does this at the same time that it uploads our other artifacts into the repository. The main benefit of doing this would be that the publishing mechanism makes sure that all modules build successfully before pushing and I would like to tap into that.

So does anybody know what the best way is to plug `docker push` into the `artifactoryPublish` task that comes with the Gradle Artifactory Plugin?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @Klara no unfortunately we never solved this. I do seem to recall a reply on one of the sites that I asked about this (or maybe it was the IRC channel because I can't seem to find the reply now) that this wouldn't fit into the gradle deployment mechanism properly. I can't remember why that was or even if I was convinced that it was... but at any rate, we gave up and just accepted the fact that we had to create custom tasks to do this.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)

Comment: I've learnt now that docker images need to be pushed to a docker registry, and this is how we currently do this: Use this gradle plugin to work with docker: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin. Our artifactory server has a docker registry configured on a specified port, we add the artifactoryhost:dockerport url in the docker/registryCredentials  closure. This leads to a docker push being made by the gradle dockerPushImage task.